# How to set session timeout at embedd jetty xml configuration?

Tags: jetty, session-timeout

I have that line of codes at my jetty-servlet-context.xml

```
<bean id="jerseyServletCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
        <property name="displayName" value="Jersey Servlet Context"/>
        <property name="contextPath" value="/rest"/>
        <property name="sessionHandler">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler"/>
        </property>
...
```

How can I add an ability to set maxInactiveInterval into my xml file? Maybe I am missing something it may be anywhere else instead of that jerseyServletCtx, but it should be at jetty-servlet-context.xml. Any ideas are welcome.

**PS:** I don't have a web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your question is almost a year old, but in case it might help you or someone else: you may want to review [`webdefault.xml`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/webdefault.xml) and check the `session-timeout` element within the session configuration section.